# Customize the hours display in Kendo Scheduler (jquery)

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, scheduler, kendo-scheduler

I would like to customize the hours display as follows:

09:00
11:00
14:00
16:00
18:00
18:30
19:00

My Code:

```
$("#schedulerQ").kendoScheduler(
{
    date: new Date('28/01/2018 09:00'),
    startTime: new Date(),
    views: [{ type: "week", 
    dateHeaderTemplate: kendo.template("<span class='days-name'>#=kendo.toString(date, 'dddd dd/MM')#</span>")}],
    minorTickCount: 1, // display one time slot per major tick
    majorTick: 60,
    allDaySlot: false,
    selectable: true,
    ...
});
```

but I have the display (per hour):

09:00
10:00
11:00
12:00
....

I need your help, Thanks.

Comment: You want to skip certain hours?

Comment: Set start time to 9 and then set

majorTick: 120

Answer (score 0):

With the standard view you can't do that. You need to create your own view. Easiest start should be copying kendo.scheduler.dayview.js and modifying it. Have a look at function "_forTimeRange".

```
            for (; idx < length; idx++) {
                var majorTickDivider = idx % (msMajorInterval / msInterval), isMajorTickRow = majorTickDivider === 0, isMiddleRow = majorTickDivider < minorTickCount - 1, isLastSlotRow = majorTickDivider === minorTickCount - 1;
                html += action(start, isMajorTickRow, isMiddleRow, isLastSlotRow);
                setTime(start, msInterval, false);
            }
```

Replace the setTime call with your custom logic. Most probably you get some side effects.
May I ask what your use case is? Maybe you can solve it without creating a custom view.